# Self harm and cutting

Tags: halacha, injury

I heard that the Rama writes that cutting oneself is *mutar* (permitted) but the Sefer Hachinuch writes that it is against the letter of the law.

Can someone provide sources for both?

Comment: If you or anyone reading this is considering self harm or cutting you may find the following resources useful. https://www.crisistextline.org/topics/self-harm/#why-do-people-self-harm-5  and   https://www.benice.org/get-help/crisis-hotline

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yosef and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: It is important to note that the commentaries to the Rema bring the opinion of the Bach that it  is forbidden.  https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.180.6?lang=bi&with=Ba%27er%20Hetev&lang2=he

Answer (score 4):

You are speaking of the [prohibition against cutting one’s self](https://outorah.org/p/6279/) and are correct.

Everyone agrees that to cut oneself in the manner of idolaters or in grief over dead people is strictly forbidden. Many (e.g., Sefer Hachinuch, Bach YD 180:6, Shach YD 180:9, Minchat Chinuch #3) also agree that it is forbidden to cut oneself for no reason but the Rema disagrees.

Specifically, in mitzva 467, Sefer Hachinuch [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.467?lang=bi)

> According to that which appears [to come out] from the words of our
> Rabbis, may their memory be blessed, (Makkot 22) the liability of the
> negative commandment is only about one who gashes himself for the dead
> or for idolatry. **But for one who gashes himself without a reason or
> from anger about his house that has fallen or his ship that has sunk -
> even though it is something extremely disgusting and ugly and
> forbidden - there is no liability of the negative commandment for
> it.**

The Rema ([YD 180:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.180.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes

> Scratching and cutting for the deceased is prohibited, even outside
> the presence of the deceased **Rema: But it is permitted to do so
> because of another source of pain**.

Note there is a linked but separate prohibition ([Chinuch 253](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.253?lang=bi)) to tattoo onself.